# Generics: Having trouble understanding why compilation fails at assignment

Tags: java, generics

Why does the following code snippet fails at c2=c1?

Compilation does not fail at c1=c0.

```
class TwoParam <X extends Runnable, Y extends X> {}
public class Main{
    <U extends Thread> void foo(){
    List<TwoParam<U, ? super Thread>> c0 = null;
    List<TwoParam<U, U>> c1 = c0;
    List<TwoParam<U, ? super Thread>> c2 = c1;
 }
}
```

while below code compiles fully:

```
class OneParam <X extends Runnable> {} 
     public class Main{
       public void bar(){
        List<OneParam<? super Runnable>> a0 = null;
        List<OneParam<Runnable>> a1 = a0;
        List<OneParam<? super Runnable>> a2 = a1;
      }
   }
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that `? super Thread` is the same type as the previous one.  In fact by using a wildcard you are basically saying they aren't.

Comment: I'm confused by what `? super Thread` is supposed to actually do.  `Object` is the only class `Thread` extends, so you're basically saying it's either a Thread or it's Object?